# I want to fadeIn only the image i click on when the square is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
console.log('Test Sourced');

var onReady2 = function() {
  console.log('memory game doc ready');

  //TODO Add your code below to attach your event listeners to functions

  //hides the images when button is clicked
  $("#revealHide").click(function() {
    $('.cardImg').fadeToggle('fast');

  });


  $(".cardDiv").click(function() {
    $(".cardImg").fadeIn('slow')
  });
};
//shows the img when clicked on the black box


// on document ready run the onReady2 function
$(document).ready(onReady2);

// revealHide function hides and shows all cards
function revealHide() {

  //TODO add your code here to get the desired functionality

}

// singleClickFunc function hides and shows an indivdual card
function singleClickFunc() {

  //TODO add your code here to get the desired functionality

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: LightCyan;
}

.cardDiv {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 6px;
  border-style: dashed;
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Assignment 6-3</title>
  <script src="vendors/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button id="revealHide" type="button">Show/Hide</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cardDiv">
    <img class="cardImg" id='cardOne' src="imgs/banana.png">
  </div>
  <div class="cardDiv">
    <img class="cardImg" id='cardTwo' src="imgs/pear.png">
  </div>
  <div class="cardDiv">
    <img class="cardImg" id='cardThree' src="imgs/orange.png">
  </div>
  <div class="cardDiv">
    <img class="cardImg" id='cardFour' src="imgs/apple.png">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

On line ***15-17*** I want to click on a blue box and only reveal that picture when I click on it

Answer (score 1):

To show the `.cardImg` in a `.cardDiv` when you click on it, use `$(this).find('.cardImg')` to target the `.cardImg` in that element instead of targeting all of them with `$('.cardImg')`

```
$(".cardDiv").on('click', function() {
    $(this).find(".cardImg").fadeIn('slow')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `$(".cardImg").fadeIn('slow')` with `$(this).find('img').fadeIn('slow')`

```js
console.log('Test Sourced');

var onReady2 = function() {
  console.log('memory game doc ready');

  //TODO Add your code below to attach your event listeners to functions

  //hides the images when button is clicked
  $("#revealHide").click(function() {
    $('.cardImg').fadeToggle('fast');

  });


  $(".cardDiv").click(function() {
    //$(".cardImg").fadeIn('slow')
    $(this).find('img').fadeIn('slow')
  });
};
//shows the img when clicked on the black box


// on document ready run the onReady2 function
$(document).ready(onReady2);

// revealHide function hides and shows all cards
function revealHide() {

  //TODO add your code here to get the desired functionality

}

// singleClickFunc function hides and shows an indivdual card
function singleClickFunc() {

  //TODO add your code here to get the desired functionality

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: LightCyan;
}

.cardDiv {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 6px;
  border-style: dashed;
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Assignment 6-3</title>
  <script src="vendors/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button id="revealHide" type="button">Show/Hide</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cardDiv">
    <img class="cardImg" id='cardOne' src="imgs/banana.png">
  </div>
  <div class="cardDiv">
    <img class="cardImg" id='cardTwo' src="imgs/pear.png">
  </div>
  <div class="cardDiv">
    <img class="cardImg" id='cardThree' src="imgs/orange.png">
  </div>
  <div class="cardDiv">
    <img class="cardImg" id='cardFour' src="imgs/apple.png">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `$(".cardImg")` is still a 'set' of matched elements, just like `$(".cardDiv")` is. If you do `$(".cardImg").anythingAtAll()` then you will perform the function on the entire set of matched elements, which is exactly the behavior you're describing. You want to add an `event listener` to each of your `.cardDiv` elements, so this part of your code is correct.

```
$(".cardDiv").click(function() {

  });
```

Once inside of the function, you want to take an action on the 'specific element' that was clicked. You DO NOT want to take an action on the entire set of matched elements inside `$('.cardImg')`. So, instead of calling the `fadeIn()` function on that matched set, call it instead on the the specific element that was clicked. When inside the function, the keyword that gives you the specific element is `this`. Once you wrap the `this` keyword inside a jquery wrapper, `$(  )`, like so `$(this)`, you can then perform jquery functions on it, like `fadeIn()` and `find()` for example. `find()` will drilldown the `DOM` tree from the clicked element and find any elements that match whatever was passed in, in this case we pass in `".cardImg"`.

Your code should be:

```
$(".cardDiv").on('click', function() {
    $(this).find(".cardImg").fadeIn('slow')
});
```